# Pyramid-Ptah for TDD enthusiasts coming from Django

Tags: tdd, pyramid, django-testing

Pyramid-Ptah does not suck, as web frameworks go. It carefully throws away the worst of all the old-school libraries that it imports, and it solves model-view-controller as elegantly as RoR or Django.

Now let's TDD that the `homepage.pt` contains the correct HTML, per any recent vandalism by us. We will add "Rumble Monkey" to `homepage.pt`, and assert we can see it in some generated HTML.

To run the `Home` page, for example, `app.py` need merely issue these lines:

```
config.add_route('home', '/')
```

And where is 'home' going? and how to test it?

Here's `HomepageView`:

```
@view_config(route_name='home',
             renderer=player.layout('shelf_ptah:homepage.lt', 'content'))
class HomepageView(object):

    def __init__(self, request):

        self.request = request

    def __call__(self):
        return {}
```

The route names are both `home`, so `HomepageView` tests it.

Next, how to test `HomepageView`? How to render it the same way the server would.

In Django, we'd use the `Client()` mock-server object:

```
def test_index(self):
    resp = self.client.get('/')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

So, how to render a input URI and get a response.content, as a string, under test, in Ptah-land?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of Pyramid suggests using [webtest](http://webtest.readthedocs.org/) for functional tests.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/testing.html#creating-functional-tests

The example from the docs:

```
import unittest

class FunctionalTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        from myapp import main
        app = main({})
        from webtest import TestApp
        self.testapp = TestApp(app)

    def test_root(self):
        res = self.testapp.get('/', status=200)
        self.assertTrue('Pyramid' in res.body)

        assert 'Rumble Monkey' == res.lxml.xpath('head/title')[0].text
```

---

I (the OP) got that working with this tweak:

```
def setUp(self):
    from app import main
    global_config = {
        '__file__': '...blah/blah/blah/settings.ini',
        'here': '..blah/blah/myapp'}
    settings = {
        'pyramid.includes': '\npyramid_debugtoolbar', 
        'sqlalchemy.url': 'sqlite:///db.sqlite', 
        'pyramid.debug_authorization': 'false', 
        'pyramid.default_locale_name': 'en', 
        'pyramid.reload_templates': 'true', 
        'pyramid.debug_notfound': 'false', 
        'pyramid.debug_templates': 'true', 
        'pyramid.debug_routematch': 'false', 
        'ptah.site_title': 'Rumble Monkey'}
    zapp = main(global_config, **settings)
    from webtest import TestApp
    self.testapp = TestApp(zapp)
```

I naturally don't know how many of those settings I can take out (or why I had to read the `settings.ini` file for the app). And I will naturally replace the `blah/blah/blah` with some `os.path.dirname(__file__)` wizardry.

Comment: Ah, it mocks a WSGI web server without actually starting one. Tx. I will confirm your answer after installing it. Also, "functional" test means something different from "view test" or "integration test", but that's a common industry misperception.

Comment: That gives the infamous `>       url = options.pop('url')
E       KeyError: 'url'` error

Comment: `pop` error fixed in response; throw two dictionaries at it. All correct style for testing.